# On click event not working when it has child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if the title is kinda confusing I'll just try and explain through code. Basically I have created a button that show or hides the cart of an e-commerce site(I'm using woocommerce). Here is a sample of the code I'm working.

[image]

**HTML Markup**

```
<div  class="crate-status toggle-cart">
    <img src="http://localhost/crate/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mini-cart-icon.png" /><span class="crate-name">Crate:</span>
    <span class="cart-contents"><?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?></span>

    <?php woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) ?>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-cart' ).on('click', function(event) {
        $('.crate-box').toggleClass('toggle');
        $('.overlay-site').toggleClass('show-overlay');
    })

    $('body').on('click', function(event) {
      if (!$(event.target).is('.toggle-cart')) {
        $('.crate-box').removeClass('toggle');
        $('.overlay-site').removeClass('show-overlay');
      }
    })

})
```

The button works fine but when I click on the child elements like img or span it doesn't seem to trigger the onclick function even though it's inside a parent element(.toggle-cart)

Here is the link to the website http://crate.ph/home/

[image]

Comment: I have debugged your code, and it seems that the answer that Nick seems to be true. The event actually fires twice..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your event handlers are firing from a single click so you're toggling it twice.  You'll be able to see the problem if you put a breakpoint in each handler.

Try adding event.stopPropagation() to the toggle-cart handler instead of the if-statement in the other handler.  Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-cart' ).on('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.crate-box').toggleClass('toggle');
        $('.overlay-site').toggleClass('show-overlay');
    })

    $('body').on('click', function(event) {
        $('.crate-box').removeClass('toggle');
        $('.overlay-site').removeClass('show-overlay');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.
It's actually is working. If you put a break point inside your

$('.toggle-cart' ).on('click', function(event) {...}

You will see it's actually triggers there.
But also this thing is being triggered:

```
$('body').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is('.toggle-cart')) {
    $('.crate-box').removeClass('toggle');
    $('.overlay-site').removeClass('show-overlay');
  }
})
```

So in condition when you click NOT .toggle-cart -> your eventListener on body hides your form

A better approach would be not to add and EventListener on entire body, but to add it on overlay you have there. Adding listeners on body is not a great thing for many cases

Answer (score -2):

This is not java script problem. This is CSS problem. You need to class="crate-name" float left.